# How to download file from firebase to app by url in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage

I wrote this question because I have small problem with using the bellow code in ionic 2.

**Note:** I got it from this link [ https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files ]

I want to get the data of my uploaded image from its url and I need help to create the downloading function and how can I use it.

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

**Note:** Here is my uploading function you may need it to know how I upload my images (its work fine)

```
constructor(...) { 
    this.myPhotosRef = firebase.storage().ref('/Photos/');
}    

uploadPhoto(DataURL){
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Saving..."
    })
    loader.present().then(_=>{
        return this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.JPEG')
        .putString(DataURL,firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
        .then((savedPicture) => {
            let tempURL = savedPicture.downloadURL;
            this.afd.list('/notesImages/').push({
                note_id: this.appService.id,
                url: tempURL,
                date: new Date().toISOString()
            });
        });
    }).then(_=>{
        loader.dismiss();
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, you have not told us where the issue is.  Where does it fail?  if its an HTTP issue what was the error code etc...

Comment: My problem in using the code of downloading .. I couldn't find tutorials that explain this for me so I don't know how can I use the code to insert url and return data url

Comment: Does `storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL()` return anything useful?

Comment: @PhilipBrack Im not sure, but my images on firebase storage. I have thier url in variable and I'm trying to use the code without problems to get the data of downloaded image

Comment: OK I am trying to write instructions now.  To be clear you have a url from firebase storage and you want to display the image in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you told me that you know how to get your image URL then I will show you an example of setting the url with `ionic start set-img-url blank`

### home.html

```
<ion-content>
  <img #myimg src=""/>
</ion-content>
```

### home.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('myimg') myImgElement;

  constructor() {

    // here is one of my personal firebase storage urls
    let url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/paystumped.appspot.com/o/map_english.png?alt=media&token=dacc1891-a71d-4c71-a812-5314d566106c';

    // just to simulate you getting that url...
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myImgElement.nativeElement.src = url;
    }, 1000);

  }

}
```

Tested this with ios and it works like a charm to set an image at a point where you determine the url dynamically using ViewChild.